# CAF basic application

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

I am trying to play a bit with CAF to create my own applciation with my own overlays like sponsors, logos, etc. (I guess this is possible?)

I started with CAF but there is very little information on it. So I created the basic application as per https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <cast-media-player></cast-media-player>
  <script>
    cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And below it says:

> At this point, a user can open their sender app, connect to their Cast
>   device, then navigate to media and press Play, which tells the
>   receiver to stream the media to the TV for the user to watch.

However I can connect with my sender app to my receiver app, but no playing is happening. If I use a default receiver, then the media is played no problem.

Comment: I've the same issue, some progress???

Comment: @AndersonK I found out i had a problem on the sender side, you can see this by debugging using chrome